# How do I add a legend for every piece of data using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a bar graph dynamically using chart.js. How could I display the legend for every color in chart.js, on the top of the bar graph?

[image]

Comment: you can see the options available here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html

Comment: Your answer takes me there, but my question is totally related to some other thing. The thing is, for every color I need to display legend on top of the bar graph. so, I get nearly Five legends on the top of the bar graph. How to do@Taj Khan?

Comment: The link from @TajKhan is correct. You don't want a legend for every color, what you want is to set a label for each dataset. A legend is one for each chart, labels are many for each datapoints inside the chart.